# multiple sessions established to socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm new to node and trying to create a server with socketio to send messages to front (react). But when I  run the server and many connections begin to be established it shows something like this :

Listening on port 3000

client connectedLv3LqI9EhmYTLBIIAAAA

client connectedrKLlxRPDkRs20L43AAAB

client connectedHAUuOADubCigGNTzAAAC

client connectedFF1dTRFe-HFublfgAAAD

Here is my code :

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const http = require("http");
const SocketIO = require("socket.io");
//database connections

let user;

const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet = rs01";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

    client.connect().then((db) => {
      let requests = 0;
      let responses = 0;
      let transactions = 0;

      const changeStream = client
        .db("gardesh_pay_silk")
        .collection("silk_profile")
        .watch();
      changeStream.on("change", (next) => {
        console.log(next);
      });
      const silkProfileQueries = client
        .db("gardesh_pay_silk")
        .collection("silk_profile_queries")
        .watch();
      silkProfileQueries.on("change", (next) => {
        console.log(next);
      });
      const silkSQLQueries = client
        .db("gardesh_pay_silk")
        .collection("silk_sqlquery")
        .watch();
      silkSQLQueries.on("change", (next) => {
        console.log(next);
        transactions += 1;
      });
      const silkRequest = client
        .db("gardesh_pay_silk")
        .collection("silk_request")
        .watch();
      silkRequest.on("change", (next) => {
        console.log(next);
        user.broadcast.emit("requested", next);
        requests++;
      });
      const silkResponse = client
        .db("gardesh_pay_silk")
        .collection("silk_response")
        .watch();
      silkResponse.on("change", (next) => {
        console.log(next);
        responses += 1;
      });
      console.log(requests);
    });

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = SocketIO(server);
io.on("connection", (client) => {
  user = client;
  console.log("client connected"+client.id);
    client.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("user disconnected");
      
    });
});



const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening on port'+port));
```

I think that the problem is in this part of code:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = SocketIO(server);
io.on("connection", (client) => {
  user = client;
  console.log("client connected"+client.id);
    client.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("user disconnected");
      
    });
});
```

and here is my connection in client side :

````
import { socketIOClient, io } from "socket.io-client";
import { type } from "jquery";

class Again extends React.Component {
  timing=()=> {
    this.props.req_changer(this.requests);
    this.props.res_changer(this.responses);
    this.props.trans_changer(this.transactions);
    this.requests = 0;
    this.responses = 0;
    this.transactions = 0;
   
  
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4000",
      requested: "undefined",
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.count = setInterval(this.timing, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.count);
  }

  render() {
    const socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint);
    socket.on("requested", (object) => {
      if (object.ns.coll == "silk_request") {
        this.requests++;
      }

      if (object.ns.coll == "silk_response") {
        this.responses++;
      }
      if (object.ns.coll == "silk_sqlquery") {
        this.transactions++;
      }
    });
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
export default Again;```
````

Answer (score 0):

There is some issues in your code.

A) Client side:
Don't put the const socket & socket.on into the render method. The render method should contain only the visualizations (UI if you want)...

The creation of the socket constant -can be- in the class's constructor, or, outside of the class:

```
const socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint);
class Again extends React.Component {
.
.
.
}
```

The listening of the sockets requests should be under the componentDidMount() function:

```
componentDidMount() {
 socket.on("requested", (object) => {
          if (object.ns.coll == "silk_request") {
            this.requests++;
          }
    
          if (object.ns.coll == "silk_response") {
            this.responses++;
          }
          if (object.ns.coll == "silk_sqlquery") {
            this.transactions++;
          }
        });
}
```

B) Server side:
this is the important issue, the 'Client' attribute you used is a socket:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
 .
 .
});
```

Every socket has a **session**. So for the same client we can have **multiple sessions** at the same time (for example, for every refreshing of the application). So you need to save the client's sessions. To do it, you can use the express session middleware:

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
  app.sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  const session = socket.request.session;
  session.save();
});
```

You need also to save all sessions (if the client use multiple navigators for exemple, the server should send the requests for all of them, bu sockets), and then to delete them when client disconnecting:

```
var onlineClients = {};
var socketToClient = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const session = socket.request.session;
  session.save();
if(onlineClients[session.clientID] === undefined){
      onlineClients[session.clientID] = {
        sockets: []
      }
    }
    socketToClient[socket.id] = session.clientID;
    onlineClients[session.clientID].sockets.push(socket);
.
.
.

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    let clientId = socketToClient[socket.id]
  if(clientId){
    let clientSockets = onlineClients[clientId].sockets
    clientSockets = clientSockets.filter(s => socket.id !== s.id)
    onlineClients[clientId].sockets = clientSockets
    if(clientSockets.length === 0){
      delete onlineClients[clientId]
    }
  }
  });
```

*Conclusion: your question title should be: multiple **sessions** established to socket io*

Hope it can help you!

Comment: thanks but still there some issues ,,first when i changed client side as you said even when i stop react server front continues to showing this error when server is down                   GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NJ5NJ0f net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.. the second problem on server side is this error which is for session middleware: TypeError: app.sessionMiddleware is not a function               please help me with this i'm total new in js

Comment: the first problem, i guess, its normal since your server is off. For the second one, add const app = require('./app'); and then const server = http.createServer(app.app); Is there an app.js in your server side project ?

Comment: for the first problem even when i shut down the react still console shows connection refused ..for the server problem i will share my server code

Comment: i noticed in source code bellow the io.on('connection') part never runs ..even when client connects to the server

Answer (score 0):

here is my node server code :

```
var app = express();
const http = require("http");
const SocketIO = require("socket.io");
//                  database connections

let user;

const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet = rs01";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

    client.connect().then((db) => {
      let requests = 0;
      let responses = 0;
      let transactions = 0;

      const changeStream = client
        .db("gardesh_pay_silk")
        .collection("silk_profile")
        .watch();
      changeStream.on("change", (next) => {
        console.log(next);
      });
      const silkProfileQueries = client
        .db("gardesh_pay_silk")
        .collection("silk_profile_queries")
        .watch();
      silkProfileQueries.on("change", (next) => {
        console.log(next);
      });
      const silkSQLQueries = client
        .db("gardesh_pay_silk")
        .collection("silk_sqlquery")
        .watch();
      silkSQLQueries.on("change", (next) => {
        console.log(next);
        transactions += 1;
      });
      const silkRequest = client
        .db("gardesh_pay_silk")
        .collection("silk_request")
        .watch();
      silkRequest.on("change", (next) => {
        console.log(next);
        user.broadcast.emit("requested", next);
        requests++;
      });
      const silkResponse = client
        .db("gardesh_pay_silk")
        .collection("silk_response")
        .watch();
      silkResponse.on("change", (next) => {
        console.log(next);
        responses += 1;
      });
      console.log(requests);
    });

const server = http.createServer(app);
var onlineClients = {};
var socketToClient = {};
const io = SocketIO.listen(4000);
io.use((socket, next) => {
  app.sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const session = socket.request.session;
  this.user = socket;
  session.save();
  if (onlineClients[session.clientID] === undefined) {
    onlineClients[session.clientID] = {
      sockets: []
    }
  }
  socketToClient[socket.id] = session.clientID;
  onlineClients[session.clientID].sockets.push(socket);
  
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    let clientId = socketToClient[socket.id]
    if (clientId) {
      let clientSockets = onlineClients[clientId].sockets
      clientSockets = clientSockets.filter(s => socket.id !== s.id)
      onlineClients[clientId].sockets = clientSockets
      if (clientSockets.length === 0) {
        delete onlineClients[clientId]
      }
    }
  });
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

it is just a very simple server that watch's for changes in mongodb...